# Gente meu codigo fica dando o erro: Notice: Undefined variable: conecta in C:\xampp\htdocs\rede\profile.php on line 25

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Meu codigo e esse aqui

```
<?php
    include("header.php");

    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $saberr = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
    $saber = mysqli_fetch_assoc($saberr);
    $email = $saber["email"];

    if ($email==$login_cookie) {
        header("Location: myprofile.php");
    }

    $pubs = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT * FROM pubs WHERE user='$email' ORDER BY id desc");

    if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
        add();
    }

    function add(){
        $login_cookie = $_COOKIE['login'];
        if (!isset($login_cookie)) {
            header("Location: login.php");
        }
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $saberr = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
        $saber = mysqli_fetch_assoc($saberr);
        $email = $saber['email'];
        $data = date("Y/m/d");

        $conf = mysqli_query($conecta, "INSERT INTO amizades ('de', 'para', 'data') VALUES ('$login_cookie','$email','data')") or die(mysqli_error($conecta));
        if ($conf) {
            header("Location: profile.php?id=".$id);
        }else{
            echo "<h3>Erro ao enviar pedido...</h3>";
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['cancelar'])) {
        cancel();
    }

    function cancel(){
        $login_cookie = $_COOKIE['login'];
        if (!isset($login_cookie)) {
            header("Location: login.php");
        }
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $saberr = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
        $saber = mysqli_fetch_assoc($saberr);
        $email = $saber['email'];

        $ins = "DELETE FROM amizades WHERE 'de'='$login_cookie' AND para='$email'";
        $conf = mysqli_query($conecta, $ins) or die(mysql_error());
        if ($conf) {
            header("Location: profile.php?id=".$id);
        }else{
            echo "<h3>Erro ao cancelar pedido...</h3>";
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['remover'])) {
        remove();
    }

    if (isset($_POST['chat'])) {
        header("Location: chat.php?from=".$id);
    }

    function remove(){
        $login_cookie = $_COOKIE['login'];
        if (!isset($login_cookie)) {
            header("Location: login.php");
        }
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $saberr = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
        $saber = mysqli_fetch_assoc($saberr);
        $email = $saber['email'];

        $ins = "DELETE FROM amizades WHERE 'de'='$login_cookie' AND para='$email' OR `para`='$login_cookie' AND de='$email'";
        $conf = mysqli_query($conecta, $ins) or die(mysqli_error());
        if ($conf) {
            header("Location: profile.php?id=".$id);
        }else{
            echo "<h3>Erro ao eliminar amizade...</h3>";
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['aceitar'])) {
        aceitar();
    }

    function aceitar(){
        $login_cookie = $_COOKIE['login'];
        if (!isset($login_cookie)) {
            header("Location: login.php");
        }
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $saberr = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
        $saber = mysqli_fetch_assoc($saberr);
        $email = $saber['email'];

        $ins = "UPDATE amizades SET 'aceite'='sim' WHERE 'de'='$email' AND para='$login_cookie'";
        $conf = mysqli_query($ins) or die(mysqli_error());
        if ($conf) {
            header("Location: profile.php?id=".$id);
        }else{
            echo "<h3>Erro ao eliminar amizade...</h3>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: $conecta está incluso no header.php? Se sim, verifique se está como global. Se não, tente declarar $conecta dentro do seu escopo dessa página e ver se o erro persiste, por favor. Pelo que eu vi, $conecta não está declarada nesse escopo.

Comment: Foi só esse erro? Se `$conecta` não existir nada no código vai funcionar pois trata-se simplesmente da variável de conexão ao banco de dados.

Comment: Eu tirei o $conecta mais aparece esses erros Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rede\profile.php on line 25

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rede\profile.php on line 26

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rede\profile.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined variable: connect in C:\xampp\htdocs\rede\profile.php on line 31
Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rede\profile.php on line 31

Answer (score 0):

Essa variável `$conecta` me parece não ter valor atribuído para ela, coloque um `$conecta = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");`, e veja se o erro foi corrigido.

Observação: Não esqueça de trocar **my_user**, **my_password**, **my_db** pelos seus dados.

Answer (score 0):

Está dizendo que **a variável conecta não possui nenhum valor atribuido.**
Se você remover essa variável e passar o código `"mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");"` **vai receber o seguinte erro:**

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rede\profile.php on line 25
```

Que quer dizer que a função `mysqli_query()` esperava 2 parâmetros e você só passou 1.

---

**Porque esse erro?**

**A função mysqli_query() precisa de 2 parâmetro obrigatórios.**

1. A conexão. Onde você especifica a conexão mysql que irá usar.*(No seu caso, a variável $conecta que passou vazia mas deveria conter a conexão)*
2. A Query. Onde você passa o comando que vai utilizar no banco de Dados.